# Pentaho Reverse Proxy: Kette

Tags: pentaho

I have setup SSL reverse proxy to redirect traffic in a way that

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name pentaho.somedomain.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/x.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/x.key.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:2000;
    }
}
```

This works fine from the borwser BUT fails from Kettle PDI, I have double checked URL its right

NO error logged in console

[image]

[image]

---

read this [Pentaho + apache Reverse Proxy + proxy SSL integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349544/pentaho-apache-reverse-proxy-proxy-ssl-integration) but my browser works fine

Comment: which pdi verion you are using?

Comment: kettle 8.2. Its seems to be an issue in mac (apple). Linux works fine